# Dynamic created map triggering warning in angular

Tags: angularjs

In angular I want to dynamically create a map based on the address entered. I have successfully done this in VueJS. But in angular this triggers security warnings.

HTML:

```
<iframe
    ng-src="https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q={{encodeURIComponent(item.address)}}&amp;output=embed"
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I have tried creating the following:

```
app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
};
```

then piping it as so:

```
| trustAsResourceUrl}}
```

Which works if using an already established URL but not since I'm trying to form URL from address. I get the following:

> Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating:  Strict
>   Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple
>   expressions when a trusted value is required.  See
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

VueJS was so simple but I can't use it in this project. I'll include it in case it gives any ideas:

```
methods: {
    getmap: function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            let addr = searchInput.value; 
            let embed = "<div class='form-group'><label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Map Preview</label><iframe frameborder = '0' scrolling= 'no' marginheight= '0' marginwidth= '0' src= 'https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q=" + encodeURIComponent(addr) + "&amp;output=embed' > </iframe></div>";

      $('.place').html(embed); }, 200)
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you can't use this filter. You have to create the string you want to use directly on the scope:

```
this.src = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://maps.google.com/maps?q="
   + encodeURIComponent(item.address) + "&output=embed");
```

Then `<iframe ng-src="{{$ctrl.src}}">`

You will have to update the entire `src` rather than just `item.address`.

Comment: That does technically answer my question so I'll accept as answer. Thank you! However, It looks slightly hard to implement into my setup. Is there a way to make a security exception for that URL structure? If so I could keep it much simpler.

Comment: You can refer to the documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce to try to get more understanding. Not sure that you have any much better options.